# How do I configure a local SOCKS server to proxy connections to a VPN tunnel?

Tags: ssh, openvpn, vpn, ssh-tunneling, socks5-proxy

I want to open an openVPN tunnel on my router (ubiquiti EdgeRouterX) and use SSH to proxy requests to that tunnel.

In other words I ONLY want requests arriving via the ssh tunnel to traverse the vpn.

Regular traffic on my network would be unchanged and follow the usual route to the public internet. However, I would like to be able to connect to my router using SOCKS5 to access the VPN tunnel (inside my network only).

Something like:
ssh -D 1234 -qCN [interface]
Instead of:
ssh -D 1234 -qCN [remote server]